# Fitting thumbnails while page is resized

Tags: html, css

Suppose I display thumbnails (~200px width each) in a web page. In a midsize screen (e.g. 15") I can display 5 thumbnails in a row.

Now what if I resize the browser window so that 5 thumbnails don't fit the page width ? I would like the number of thumbnails to be changed automatically to fit the page.

For example: suppose, 5 thumbnails with spaces between them take ~2000 px. Now I am resizing the window. When the page width becomes < 2000 px but > 1600 px. I would like to display 4 thumbnails in a row and so on.

What HTML/CSS markup should I use to achieve that behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/gawcP/) to explain media queries to someone. You can use a similar design, although it's usually much simpler just to `float:left` or `display:inline-block` your elements and let the browser take care of the rest.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/gawcP/)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a responsive layout. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) provides the same by default.

Another way is by using `@media` tags. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp . Here, you will need to make a function like this:
Get the screen size using `mediacheck` and then set up thresholds using `@media`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [float property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) for this:

```
float: left;
```

Floating elements will wrap when they do not fit in the parent's width.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/c85jb/) (try resizing the page)

Comment: Yes. It should wrap automatically if you float each thumbnail element (doesn't have to be a `div`).